# Extrude Arch like in the video

Tags: extrude

I found a video about [Gothic Arch modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRsoVJb3ids) on Youtube using Blender 2.78.

At 1:28 the creator extrudes the vertices of the arch.

However, I can't figure out how it was done. The keydisplay does not show any special shortcuts. The extrude settings on the left seems to be default.

How to reproduce this extruding behaviour? 
Any shortcuts or settings changes? Additional plugins?

I guess some shortcut since there is that small (black) gizmo with the dottet line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Addon, plain Blender.

The arch was mirrored.
[image: arch]
The mirrored arch is extruded along the normals and meet in the middle. Like the extrusion in the video.
[image: extrusion with mirrored editor cage]
Here the view with only one side editable:
[image]

Side note:
Without the mirror if you have the whole arch. You can archive something similar with extrude followed by scale. <kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: yes, it is mirrored but around the other axis (1:20). I will give it a try to mirror it like you did.

Comment: managed to do it mirrored along the long side, with face select, extrude regions (vertex normals). Just extrude, not move, and afterwards scale. Not like in the video but the same smooth behaviour and good results. Thanks for the tipp.